# after joining two dataframes it is not giving the accurate values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have two dataframes 1 is books1 with Schema

```
root
|-- asin: string (nullable = true)
|-- helpful: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|-- overall: double (nullable = true)
|-- reviewText: string (nullable = true)
|-- reviewTime: string (nullable = true)
|-- reviewerID: string (nullable = true)
|-- reviewerName: string (nullable = true)
|-- summary: string (nullable = true)
|-- unixReviewTime: long (nullable = true)
```

and another is label with schema

```
root
 |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
```

books1 and label contains

[image]

but now when i am joining them with join command,

`var bookdf = books1.join(label)`
the output is not correct
[image]

value field should have contain 2,6,0 but it is containing only 2 why it is happening no. of rows in both the dataframes are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `join` two dataframes whithout providing the joining expression

If both the dataframe have the same number of rows then you can create a new column as `id` which is a `row number`  for both dataframe as

```
val newBookDF = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  book1.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
  },
  // Create schema for index column
  StructType(book1.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false))
)
```

And same for the `label` dataframe

```
val newLabelDF = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  label.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
  },
  // Create schema for index column
  StructType(label.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false))
)
```

Now you can `join` final two dataframes like

```
newBookDF.join(newLabelDF, Seq("id")).drop("id")
```

This will give you result as you expected